# mySQL. Consulta anidada sobre una tabla

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

os traigo una duda que tengo sobre una consulta que me trae de cabeza. Tengo una sola tabla que viene heredada de un proyecto anterior.

En la tabla entre otros muchos datos, tengo un DNI, una fecha de certificado (FCert) y una fecha de renovación (FRev). En esta tabla se almacena un registro cada vez que alguien va y se hace un certificado. Así que tiene muchas personas repetidas y no tiene un ID único.

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que me devuelva la gente que se hizo un certificado en 2006 (YEAR(FCert) = 2006) y volvió a hacerse uno en 2016 (YEAR(FRev) = 2016). Es decir que en la tabla tiene que haber dos registros de DNI, uno con cada dato.

OS adjunto la consulta como la tengo ahora, pero me devuelve valores raros y duplicados.

```
SELECT a.`DNI`, a.`tabla`, a.`FRev`, a.`FCert`, a.`FNac` FROM `tabla` AS a JOIN tabla AS b ON (a.DNI = b.DNI) 
WHERE YEAR(a.`FRev`) = 2016 AND YEAR(b.`FCert`) = 2016 
ORDER BY a.`DNI` DESC
```

Si me podeis echar un cable, estoy atrapado ahí.

Comment: Probá con el INNER JOIN

Comment: Qué error te marca esa consulta o cual es el problema?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua.

Si he entendido bien, tú quieres los datos de las personas que han sacado el documento en el año `2006` y lo han renovado en el año `2016`.

Entonces, no tienes necesidad de hacer un `JOIN` de la tabla sobre sí misma, sino aplicar dos criterios con `OR` para cada campo respectivo.

### [<kbd>AQUÍ PUEDES VER DEMO COMPLETO</kbd>](http://rextester.com/QPHT39254)

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla_unica_20180115 
WHERE YEAR(f_cert)=2006 OR YEAR(f_rev)=2016 
ORDER BY dni DESC;
```

**Resultado:**

```
id  dni     f_cert                  f_rev
1   100     15.01.2006 00:00:00     NULL
5   100     NULL                    16.01.2016 00:00:00
4   92      19.01.2006 00:00:00     NULL
7   92      NULL                    20.01.2016 00:00:00
2   80      16.01.2006 00:00:00     NULL
6   80      NULL                    17.01.2016 00:00:00
```

Y si quieres agrupar, de forma que te muestre sólo las personas individuales que lo han hecho, sin filas duplicadas:

```
SELECT dni
FROM tabla_unica_20180115 
WHERE YEAR(f_cert)=2006 OR YEAR(f_rev)=2016 
GROUP BY dni 
ORDER BY dni DESC;
```

**Resultado:**

```
dni
100
92
80
```